# Can one get information about US federal misdemeanor citations?

Tags: united-states, federal-courts

[According to New Hampshire Public Radio](https://www.nhpr.org/post/border-patrol-checkpoint-woodstock-yields-alleged-immigration-violations), in June 2019,

> Officials with U.S. Customs and Border Protection issued tickets to 29 people for alleged immigration violations at a checkpoint on I-93 near Woodstock on Sunday.
>
> The violations were for legal visitors to the U.S. who didn’t have appropriate paperwork on them, as required by law, accordign [sic] to the CBP.

Will there be any information in the public record concerning these citations?  I suspect that they allege violations of [8 USC 1304(e)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1304#e).  Is there any way to confirm that?

Nine years ago, [an article on the American Immigration Lawyers Association's blog](https://thinkimmigration.org/blog/2010/06/03/i-have-read-the-arizona-law-and-it-still-stinks/) stated that "a search of court records reveals no prosecutions federally for this offense."  If the federal government has started trying to enforce that statute after not having done so for some long period of time, it seems like it should be big news.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it's expensive.

Federal court records -- including misdemeanor citations -- are available through [PACER](https://www.pacer.gov).

Comment: Not that expensive. It's pennies per downloaded document page billed quarterly but free if the number is small. Searches that you do prior to downloading a document are free.

Comment: This is excellent news. Have they changed the fee structure, or was I just doing it wrong back when I used to use it? I could have sworn I was getting charged just to search or look at a docket.

Comment: I use it every month or two and its been that way for a while, but I didn't pay attention to how it was billed back in the days when I wasn't paying for it, so I don't recall when the current fee structure was put in place.